# Cannot use 'new' with the Function type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have this code:

```
const BlockConstructors: Function[] = [
 OBlock,
 IBlock,
 TBlock
];

function randomFromArray(array: any[]) {
  return array[Math.floor( Math.random() * array.length )];
}

const BlockConstructor: Function = random(BlockConstructors);
const block: Block = new BlockConstructor();
```

I try to draw a some block constructor from array and then create a new object, all my block constructors in array extends Block class. I get error:

> Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.

Why this error appears?

Comment: Const are supposed to be to a const value and you are not suppose to make a new reference to a const value.

Comment: why would you want to make a new instance of something that doesn't change anyway? :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code isn't self-contained, but here's the boiled down reason.

`Function` isn't `new`-able. Only three  things can be `new`'d in TypeScript:

1. Types with *construct* signatures
2. Types with no construct signatures, but with *call* signatures that return `void`
3. `any`

You really want the first one.

Try switching from `Function` to `(new () => Block)`.